# Final processing of a loop with multiple completionHandlers

Tags: c#, loops, completionhandler

I'm looping over a list of items that each has a method to handle some processing.  This method takes in an Action completionHandler that is called when the item in done with its own processing.

I need a method called once all of the items in the loop have completed. How can this be handled in C#? (Also, how would you go about handling cases where one of the items fails to process but you are willing to ignore it?)

Comment: if the actions you run are independent one from another, there is no reason worrying about failed method in chain (from execution completeness perspective). what is a problem ?

Comment: The problem I am having is I was attempting to run my final processing method once the loop was complete, but because the completionHandlers  are handled in a separate thread, I don't know if/when they have all at least attempted to complete.

Comment: you need to have some state machine (variable, array of variables) which every thread once completed/failed set in some state and main thread once in a while checks it, via timer. More appropriate, imo solution would be to run those tasks in another thread and handle feedback from them in the main thread. You avoid so once a while state check. Look on `Task<T>::ContinueWith(..)`